# Parsing a value with a dimension in Android

Tags: android, string-parsing, dimension

What is the proper way to parse a value with a dimension in Android? For example, I would want to get an `int` with a value of 20 from any of these strings: `20px`, `20mm`, `20dp`.

Trying `Integer.parseInt()` doesn't get me very far because it throws an exception on non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

If the unit is always present and is only one of the mentioned AND you are sure you won't ever need it - simply parse a substring `str.substring(0, str.length() - 3)`

I would recommend using a custom class to parse and hold the value including the unit - you might need it sometime.

Comment: I'm wondering if something like this is already built into the Android SDK. Seems like it would be something commonly used.

Comment: I'm sure that there is something in Android that does this used when parsing the UI layout XML. I can't find any indication that it is public though - and for the rather small problem stated here it would be a matter of minutes writing a class to parse and hold the parsed value. :o)

Answer (score 0):

If you start with an `AttributeSet`, you can obtain a `TypedArray` through a `Context` and eventually use `getDimension` or a related function.

If you just want to pass a string to parseInt without throwing an exception try this:

```
Integer.parseInt( someString.replaceFirst( "[^0-9].*" , "" ) );
```

The regular expression truncates the string starting at the first character that is not a digit.  Which implies that the string must start with a digit.